# DVB device wont work (RTL2832U I guess), wont even appear at /dev/dvb

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, vlc, dvb

I bought two DVB devices. One was for the wrong region (USA and I'm in Brazil). This one I can use at VLC and even scan for channels, but obviously nothing will come up.

Now for the right one for the Brazil region, when I plug into my PC I get nothing in `lsusb`

I try to open `/dev/dvb/adapter0` on VLC but it won't work. It's worth nothing that there is no `/dev/dvbX` files anyway

I don't know how but I think I found out that mine is the RTL2832U. I een found old kernel drivers for it: https://github.com/ambrosa/DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0 but they won't compile because it's for a very old kernel.

What can I do to make it work? I'm running a conventional ubuntu 17.10.1.

**UPDATE:**

I thought the Realtek that appeared at lsusb was from the dvb tuner but it's not so I edited

**UPDATE 2**

if it doesn't appear in lsusb it means its broken?

```
UPDATE 3:

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler G4
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2341:0001 Arduino SA Uno (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: How about showing us: `lsusb` Also, remove the device and then run: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` Insert the device. Are there any interesting messages as the device is inserted? Get out of 'tail' with Ctrl+c.

Comment: @chili555 I added an update. Nothing changes in lsusb after I plug or unplug the device. And nothing shows in syslog when I plug it. Does it mean its broken? Its light turns on when I plug it though

Comment: "Nothing changes in lsusb after I plug or unplug the device. And nothing shows in syslog when I plug it. Does it mean its broken?" I'm afraid so. Sorry.